# Setting up environment for debugging - Intellij Tomcat Maven

Tags: java, maven, debugging, intellij-idea, tomcat7

I've been attempting to set up a remote debug configuration in IntelliJ.

The application itself is deployed via tomcat7 plug on the command line and works as expected.

Now I would like to debug this application and am unsure how to connect a remote debugger in this case.

I have edited tomcat startup.bat

> set JDPA_ADDRESS=8080 set JDPA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket

and set up a remote config in IntelliJ

[image: debug config]

When the debugger configuration gets run, "handshake failed" error appears.

Answer (score 0):

Port 8080 is usually a HTTP port used by Tomcat, your debugger port must be different.